# Sending request to local computer from anywhere

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, port-forwarding

Few days ago I have made an application on raspberrypi that turn on the alight when you send to it an http request "http://rspi:8080/light". Secondly I have made an Android application that sends that request to it. Everything works fine when both devices are in the same network. My question is: how i can send this request from any other network. How I have to connect or how make route from my phone to this raspberry pi?

Comment: Pay someone (your ISP or a cloud service) for a public IP, route this via VPN or otherwise to your RaspPi. Some ISPs (mine, for example) give you a public IPv6 address you can use. Less and less ISPs (not mine) give you a public IPv4 for free, most use carrier grade NAT today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure port forwarding on your router. So for example port 5600 on the WAN IP would be forwarded to your LAN rspi, port 8080. Then anybody connecting to your external IP:5600 (assigned by your ISP provider) would actually connect to rspi:8080. It would help to have a static external IP in this case, or a DynDNS type of service. Another option is to configure a RemoteForward ssh tunnel from your rspi to some external machine with ssh service under your control, with something like:

```
ssh -R 5600:localhost:8080 external_server_ip
```

Comment: external_server_ip should be my phone ip?

Comment: I want to control it from any network

Comment: No, the external IP would be any IP under your control, like a cloud AWS node or similar. The easy way is to just configure the port forwarding on the router, then the external IP is your router IP at the time of the connection. Since ISPs assign them dynamically, it may change when the router is turned off and on again.

Comment: Having your machines externally available usually costs money. You either have to pay your provider for the external IP that never changes, or pay a DynDNS kind of service to route your ever-changing dynamic external IP through their system, or you would have to pay for a cloud node, that is externally available.

Comment: thanks for your help